# Selecionar uma linha do objeto listbox

Tags: vba

Tenho uma planilha (PLan1), com suas células listadas num `listbox1`, gostaria de capturar uma linha com várias células de informação e listá-la num `userform`, como devo fazer?

Answer (score 1):

Creio que a melhor solução seria usar um ComboBox no UserForm.

Minha sugestão é seguir os passos abaixo:

1. Crie uma tabela e nomeie um intervalo (ex. lst_Esporte)
2. Crie um formulário e codifique para carregar os dados na inicialização do formulário, como fazer isso? Segue abaixo um código e um modelo de planilha que fiz para responder essa pergunta.

Código:

```
Private Sub btn_populate_Click()
' Botão para carregar os dados

' Limpa os dados do combobox
cmb_esporte.Clear

' Busca os dados que irá para a lista
Dados = Range("lst_Esporte")

' Carrega os dados no combobox
With cmb_esporte
    For Each Item In Dados
    .AddItem Item
    Next Item
End With

' Coloque valor padrão - caso aplicável
cmb_esporte.Value = "Escolha sua opção"

End Sub
```

Link com o modelo que fiz: [modelo](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=7A3D691330A912A!18065&authkey=!AJOQw3FUuuxyqEg&ithint=file%2Cxlsm)

Espero ter ajudado!